# MPI_SSEND : How does it guarantee reuse of the sender buffer?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I understand that `MPI_Bsend` will save the sender's buffer in local buffer managed by MPI library, hence it's safe to reuse the sender's buffer for other purposes.
What I do not understand is how `MPI_Ssend` guarantee this?

> Send in synchronous mode.
>
> A send that uses the synchronous mode can be started whether or not a matching receive was posted. However, the send will complete successfully only if a matching receive is posted, and the receive operation has started to receive the message sent by the synchronous send. Thus, the completion of a synchronous send not only indicates that the send buffer can be reused, but also indicates that the receiver has reached a certain point in its execution, namely that it has started executing the matching receive

As per above, `MPI_Ssend` will return (ie allow further program execution) if matching receive has been posted and it has started to receive the message sent by the synchronous send. **Consider the following case:**

I send a huge data array of `int` say `data[1 million]` via `MPI_Ssend`. Another process starts receiving it (but might not have done so completely), which allows `MPI_Ssend` to return and execute the next program statement. The next statement makes changes to the buffer at very end `data[1 million] = \*new value*\`. Then the `MPI_Ssend` finally reaches the buffer end and sends this new value which was not what I wanted.

What am I missing in this picture?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

`MPI_Ssend()` is both **blocking** and **synchronous**.

From the MPI 3.1 standard (chapter 3.4, page 37)

> Thus, the completion of a synchronous send not only indicates
>   that the **send buffer can be reused**, but it also indicates that the
>   receiver has reached a certain point in its execution, namely that it
>   has started executing the matching receive.